# Is this synchronization on ConcurrentHashMap correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have a key-value map accessed by multiple threads:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Key, VersionValue> key_vval_map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Key, VersionValue>();
```

My custom `get()` and `put()` methods follow the typical `check-then-act` pattern. Therefore, synchronization is necessary to ensure atomicity. To avoid locking the whole `ConcurrentHashMap`, I define:

```
private final Object[] locks = new Object[10];
{
    for(int i = 0; i < locks.length; i++) 
        locks[i] = new Object();
}
```

And the `get()` method goes (it calls the `get()` method of `ConcurrentHashMap`):

```
public VersionValue get(Key key)
{
    final int hash = key.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    synchronized (locks[hash % locks.length])   // I am not sure whether this synchronization is necessary.
    {
        VersionValue vval = this.key_vval_map.get(key);
        if (vval == null)   
            return VersionValue.RESERVED_VERSIONVALUE;  // RESERVED_VERSIONVALUE is defined elsewhere
        return vval;
    }
}
```

The `put()` method goes (it calls the `get()` method above):

```
public void put(Key key, VersionValue vval)
{
    final int hash = key.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF;

    synchronized (locks[hash % locks.length])   // allowing concurrent writers
    {
        VersionValue current_vval = this.get(key);  // call the get() method above

        if (current_vval.compareTo(vval) < 0)   //  it is an newer VersionValue
            this.key_vval_map.put(key, vval);
    }
}
```

The above code works. But, as you know, working is far from being correct in multi-threaded programming.

**My questions are :**

1. Is this synchronization mechanism (especially `synchronized (locks[hash % locks.length])`) necessary and correct in my code?
2. In [Javadoc on Interface Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html), it says

> Lock implementations provide more extensive locking operations than
>   can be obtained using synchronized methods and statements.

Then is it feasible to replace `synchronization` by `Lock` in my code?

**Edit:** If you are using Java-8, don't hesitate to refer to the answer by @nosid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConcurrentMap` allows you to use optimistic locking instead of explicit synchronization:

```
VersionValue current_vval = null;
VersionValue new_vval = null;

do {
    current_vval = key_vval_map.get(key);

    VersionValue effectiveVval = current_vval == null ? VersionValue.RESERVED_VERSIONVALUE : current_vval;

    if (effectiveVval.compareTo(vval) < 0) {
        new_vval = vval;
    } else {
        break;
    }
} while (!replace(key, current_vval, new_vval));

...

private boolean replace(Key key, VersionValue current, VersionValue newValue) {
    if (current == null) {
        return key_vval_map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue) == null;
    } else {
        return key_vval_map.replace(key, current, newValue);
    }
}
```

It will probably have better performance under low contention.

Regarding your questions:

1. If you use Guava, take a look at [`Striped`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html)
2. No, you don't need additional functionality of `Lock` here

Comment: `ConcurrentMap allows you to use optimistic locking instead of explicit synchronization`: could you please give some references and say something more about `optimistic locking`? It is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I think I have understood your smart idea of `optimistic locking` using `while (!replace(key, current_vval, new_vval));`.  And `Striped` is also what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Java-8, you can use the method [ConcurrentHashMap::merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) instead of reading and updating the value in two steps.

```
public VersionValue get(Key key) {
    return key_vval_map.getOrDefault(key, VersionValue.RESERVED_VERSIONVALUE);
}

public void put(Key key, VersionValue vval) {
    key_vval_map.merge(key, vval,
        (lhs, rhs) -> lhs.compareTo(rhs) >= 0 ? lhs : rhs);
}
```